# How do I send a custom templatized e-mail from a Jenkins Pipeline script?

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

I would like my Jenkins Pipeline jobs to send a custom e-mail report when they fail.  Sending a custom e-mail is fairly straightforward:

```
mail(
  to: 'recipient@example.com',
  from: 'no-reply@example.com', 
  replyTo: 'no-reply@example.com', 
  subject: 'your custom jenkins report', 
  body: 'custom report here',
)
```

However, I would like to render some kind of template and inject it into the message body.  I don't care exactly what templating language is used (Jinja, ERB, something else...?). I would like put my template in a git repository as well.  How can I do this?  I'm thinking something along these lines:

```
checkout([
  $class: 'GitSCM',
  userRemoteConfigs: [[url: 'https://git.example.com/custom-report.git']],
  branches: [[name: '*/master']],
])

reportBody = renderTemplate(file: 'custom-report/custom-report.template')

mail(
  to: 'recipient@example.com',
  from: 'no-reply@example.com', 
  replyTo: 'no-reply@example.com', 
  subject: 'your custom jenkins report', 
  body: reportBody,
)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to do this with a [shared library](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/shared-libraries/) (though shared libraries aren't necessary; you can just put these steps directly into your pipeline, but it does make a few things slightly more convenient).  I created a global shared library with the following files:

`resources/report.txt.groovy`:

```
Hello from ${job}!
```

`vars/helpers.groovy`:

```
import groovy.text.StreamingTemplateEngine

def renderTemplate(input, variables) {
  def engine = new StreamingTemplateEngine()
  return engine.createTemplate(input).make(variables).toString()
}
```

Then, in my Pipeline, I added the following step:

```
variables = [ job: currentBuild.rawBuild.getFullDisplayName() ]
template = libraryResource('report.txt.groovy')
report = helpers.renderTemplate(template, variables)

mail(
  to: 'recipient@example.com',
  from: 'no-reply@example.com', 
  replyTo: 'no-reply@example.com', 
  subject: 'your custom jenkins report', 
  body: report,
)
```

This generates an email with the following content:

```
Hello from SIS Unix Automation Testing » myjob » master #29!
```

where `SIS Unix Automation Testing » myjob » master` is the full name of my Multibranch Pipeline job.

Note that you will need to disable the sandbox or approve/whitelist scripts to use this approach, as some of the internals of `StreamingTemplateEngine` will be blocked otherwise.

The docs for `StreamingTemplateEngine` are available [here](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/next/html/documentation/template-engines.html).